# Parent Component not Passing Firebase props to Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a parent component where I have initialized a Firebase instance and I need to submit a form in a child component where it takes the initialized firebase props and submits the data to cloud firestore. My problem is that whenever I try to submit the form details in the child component I get the error **Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined**

Please see my codes below where I have initialized my Firebase props and where I pass the props to my child component:

```
import { withFirebase } from "../../utils/Firebase";

const SignUpDetail = (props) => {
 const renderSwitch = (id) => {
  switch (id) {
   case "subscribe":
    return <Subscribe {...props} />;
   case "finish":
    return <FinishSetup {...props} />;
   default:
    return null;
 }
};
}
export default withRouter(withFirebase(SignUpDetail));
```

This is the method i use on a button in the parent that works ****editted****

```
const handleSignUp = (event) => {
props.firebase
  .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    formState.values.email,
    formState.values.password
  )
  .then((authUser) => {
    return props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set(
      {
        email: formState.values.email,
        policy: formState.values.policy,
        subscribe: formState.values.subscribe,
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  })
  .then(() => {
    setFormState({ ...formState });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error: " + error);
  });

event.preventDefault();
};
```

Then in my child component this is where I receive the props

```
const Subscribe = ({ props }) => {
  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   props.firebase
  .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    formState.values.email,
    formState.values.password
  )
  .then((authUser) => {
    // Create a user in your Firebase realtime database

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error: " + error);
  });
};
}
```

If I make any frebase calls from the parent it works but if I make any call from the child it doesnt work and I get this error.
I will appreciate it if I could get a help.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you were making calls from from parent?

Comment: @AsifM I have updated my question. I use a method to call the firebase instance where I save the save to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Firebase Context where I started an instance of the Firebase and anytime I needed that instance in  Child component, I make a reference to it and I am able to use it without any problems. In that case I do not need to pass Firebase instance as a props.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you pass the props properly?

what you get for `console.log(props)`
in the child component?

Comment: I have changed the entire flow so I do not have those codes anymore to log the props. I have resolved it with the new flow. However, I have a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839354/react-set-a-state-of-a-component-as-part-of-a-form-state if you could assist me.